# How many afghans, who've worked with the US are still in country?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, afghanistan

According to current Taliban's speed, it's a question of time, how long would Ghani's government would stand. For the last week they've captured about 10 provinces:
[image]

I've read about US evacuating afghan personnel, which was involved in maintaining US presence in country - interpreters, and others.

Is there any information about how many already evacuated/still in Afghanistan?

Comment: The actual number might depend on how you count. It is very well possible that the Taliban will consider people collaborators the US asylum system would not. Also remember that the US is not the only country involved in the [Resolute Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolute_Support_Mission) mission.

Comment: @Philipp quite so. Here in Germany I have met with refugees who hauled freight for the coalition troops. By Taliban standards, they are traitors who need to be killed, by German standards they are lorry drivers who illegally immigrated to Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [NPR article](https://www.npr.org/2021/07/29/1021235878/waiting-for-u-s-visas-afghan-interpreters-fear-the-taliban) says:

> [Afghanistan veteran Matt] Zeller works with a group called the Association of Wartime Allies, which has been pushing to extricate approximately 70,000 Afghan interpreters and family members.

I then went to the AWA's web site, and it says:

> Over 88,000 wartime allies and their families need evacuation from Afghanistan. The U.S. Government is only moving hundreds per week.

and

> We need your help to help save the 18,000 translators who have applied and are awaiting Special Immigrant Visas for their service.

I'm not sure why this last quote is so much lower than the 70,000 number Zeller mentioned. Maybe the rest haven't even applied for visas yet, and need assistance with getting the process started.

Comment: The difference between "18,000 translators" and "70,000 Afghan interpreters and family members" is presumably "52,000 family members"

Comment: Maybe, but what about "88,000 wartime allies and their families"? If interpreted literally, 88,000 doesn't include the family members.